# Formula to compare two different range and count the different

Tags: excel, compare, excel-formula

How to compare two or more data range and count the different by using excel formula?

Suppose I have two sheets:

```
---FIRST SHEET---
Personal Number | Name
10001           | A1
10002           | A2
10003           | A3
10004           | A4

---SECOND SHEET---
Personal Number | Name
10003           | A3
10004           | A4
10005           | A5
```

count of different is 2 (1001, 1002) from first sheet view and 1 (10005) from second sheet view. Can excel generate formula something like this:

```
=COUNT('Sheet 1'!A1:A4) - COUNT(INTERSECT('Sheet 1'!A1:A4, 'Sheet 2'!A1:A3)) // output 2
=COUNT('Sheet 2'!A1:A4) - COUNT(INTERSECT('Sheet 1'!A1:A4, 'Sheet 2'!A1:A3)) // output 1
```

Comment: `=COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,Sheet1!A1)` in Sheet1 say in Cell `C2` and Drag it Down. `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,Sheet2!A1)` in sheet2 cell `c2` and drag it down. then `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!B:B,0)` in sheet1 say in cell `D2`, will give output1 and `=COUNTIF(Sheet2!B:B,0)` in Sheet1 Cell `D3` will give output2.

Answer (score 0):

The array formula(*) indicates how many cells are common to the ranges Range1 and Range2

```
{=SUM(COUNTIF(Range1,Range2))}
```

This can be easily extended

```
{=COUNTA(Range1)-SUM(COUNTIF(Range1,Range2))}
```

indicates how many cells are in Range1 but not in Range2

Care is needed if either Range1 or Range2 contain non-unique values (i.e. more than one cell in the range has same value) as each such duplicate gets counted (so if you had a value which occurs twice in Range1 and 3 times in Range2, this would equate to 6 matches from this one value).

You can test whether a range contains duplicates or not using

```
{=COUNTA(Range1)-SUM(COUNTIF(Range1,Range1))}
```

If Range1 has no duplicates the value will be zero. If the value is negative then duplicates exist in Range1. Figuring out the pattern of duplicates from the value is a little more tricky but that, perhaps, is for another time.

(*) An array formula appears in curly braces in the formula bar and are created by pressing Ctl+Shift+Enter rather than just Enter when editting in the formula bar.